# Qt4Dotnet on Mac OS X

Tags: qt, macos, qt4, qt4dotnet

I'm using [Qt4Dotnet project](http://code.google.com/p/qt4dotnet/) in order to port application originally written in C# on Linux and Mac. Port to Linux hasn't taken much efforts and works fine. But Mac (10.4 Tiger) is a bit more stubborn.

The problem is: when I try to start my application it throws an exception. Exception states that `com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer` is unable to find all necessary ibraries. QtJambi library initializer uses `java.library.path` VM environment variable. This variable includes current working directory. I put all necessary libraries in a working directory. When I try to run the application from MonoDevelop IDE, initializer is able to load one library, but the other libraries are 'missing':

`An exception was thrown by the type initializer for com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer ---> java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far:
No 'qtjambi-deployment.xml' found in classpath, loading libraries via 'java.library.path'
Loading library: 'libQtCore.4.dylib'...
 - using 'java.library.path'
 - ok, path was: /Users/chin/test/bin/Debug/libQtCore.4.dylib
Loading library: 'libqtjambi.jnilib'...
 - using 'java.library.path'`

Both `libQtCore.4.dylib` and `libqtjambi.jnilib` are in the same directory. When I try to run it from the command prompt, the initializer is unable to load even `libQtCore.4.dylib`.

I'm using Qt4Dotnet v4.5.0 (currently the latest) with QtJambi v4.5.2 libraries. This might be the source of the problem, but I'm neither able to compile Qt4Dotnet v4.5.2 by myself nor to find QtJambi v4.5.0 libraries. Project's page states that some sort of patch should be applied to QtJambi's source code in order to be compatible with Mono framework, but this patch hasn't been released yet. Without this patch application crashes in a strange manner (other than library seek fault).

I must note that original QtJambi loads all necessary libraries perfectly, so it might be issues of IKVM compiler used to translate QtJambi into .Net library.

Any suggestions how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into the same problem earlier today.  As soon as I copied libikvm-native.dylib from my current Mono to my project's exe directory, it worked.  Frank reminded me to do that [on the list here](http://groups.google.com/group/qt4dotnet/browse_thread/thread/708a01eb8cba881b#).